# How can I remove ":" from the elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am Trying to convert the array [ '9:00', '9:40', '9:50', '11:00', '15:00', '18:00' ] to   [ '900', '940', '950', '1100', '1500', '1800' ]   in javascript.

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `.map()` function. This function iterates over all items in the array, allowing you to execute code on said iterations. Use what I've provided below.

```
const arrayOfTimestamps = [ '9:00', '9:40', '9:50', '11:00', '15:00', '18:00' ];

const formattedTimestamps = arrayOfTimestamps.map(time => time.replace(/:/g, ''))
```

As an explanation, `.map()` iterates over each item, and the time is being handled by regex. the `/g` aka global flag tells the regex to remove all semicolors's from the strings.

For more information on how `.map()` works, here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way:-

```
let oldArray = ['9:00', '9:40', '9:50', '11:00', '15:00', '18:00'];
let newArray = oldArray.map(elem => elem.replace(':',''));
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are other solutions that use less lines of code, the following is easier to read. Loop through your list of dates and for each date, replace the colon character with a blank.

```
var list = [ '9:00', '9:40', '9:50', '11:00', '15:00', '18:00' ];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
  list[i] = list[i].replace(':', ''); 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a regular expression for this similar to this one:

```
var regExpStuff = /[/:]/;
var array = removeItem(unique, regExpStuff);
```

Then you need a remove function with splice method and using the regex above:

```
function removeItem(originalArray, itemToRemove) {
    var j = 0;
    while (j < originalArray.length) {
        if (originalArray[j] == itemToRemove) {
            originalArray.splice(j, 1);
    } else { j++; }
}
return originalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to apply a callback to each element of the array, and return the processed result.

```js
let arr = ['9:00', '9:40', '9:50', '11:00', '15:00', '18:00']
arr = arr.map(v => v.replace(/:/g, '')
```

Flag `g` for Regex will replace all `:` occurrences. Without it only the first `:` will be removed.